# MDI forms disable/enable specific controls

Tags: vb.net

Have some new challenge regarding my application as user requested application to be able to disable some controls which are placed all over my windows forms mdi program for specific users. I've prepared already shared class which containing user name but i have no idea how to mark some controls to be disable as control are placed on all different parent forms, child forms and so on. How to achieve that?

Comment: The way I have always done that is to add something like a access-level to the user class.  Then some other class does the same for certain controls (usually by name). When a form loads, it gets a collection indicating which controls are disabled for this user-session (based on `UserAccess <= ThisControl.RequiredLevel`).  These typically tend to grow in breadth and complexity, so dont hardcode anything.

Comment: hmm nice idea but how to achieve that? My program is loading then user logging to program, after that Main mdi windows poping up and user is saved into Shared class user, let's say i put him to option - "disable editing" which would mean all controls like "Add", "Edit", "Delete" on all different forms will be disabled. How to achieve that? Especially when having lot of modal, show dialog forms which comming from diffrent parents etc..

Comment: "editing" is too broad.  You will run into those who can edit but not delete for example.  You'll also likely run into those who cant even go to certain forms. The data for the access level could be in a DB or even a serialized file; if you define them in code, you will have to recompile when someone is hired or promoted.

Comment: In future i will do this in serialized XML form but for now what i need is to disable given bulk of controls located in different mdi places - question is: How to do it choosing most fastest way?

Comment: As I said, when a form loads, it submits the form name and user level to some class designed to track this.  The class returns a list of controls which are disabled for that user.  XML may be mistake.

Comment: could you provide any sample what you saying would be appreciated. Forgot to mention about messsage box's messages which should be taken into it.

Comment: What i am currently have on mind is to check for all Load events for all of the forms and change the control Name property to what i want, but how to apply that for text boxes?

Comment: I have remarkably little to go on here for any sort of access control system.  I have no idea how msgboxes play into this or what you intend for the Name property.  As I said, I would probably disable them (TBs too). If some task related controls were in GroupBoxes or Tabs the whoe set could be disabled.

Comment: i have idea to change language for controls like buttons, labels etc. - i can use Load event. On the application start user could switch betwen languages and there would be shared class which would keep language info, then in Load event controls like buttons, labels etc names could be changed. Problem is i have no idea how to change messageboxes text.

Comment: Globalization is something quite different and not mentioned in the question, hence my confusion.  Also changing the Name wont help the user (I think you mean the `.Text`).